# How to nest tables in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, nested, r-caret

I read that it is possible to store dataframes in a column of a dataframe with nest:
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html

Is it also possible to store *tables* in a column of a dataframe?

The reason is that I would like to calculate the Kappa for every subgroup of a dataframe with Caret. Although caret::confusionMatrix(t) expects a table as input.

In the example-code below this works fine if I calculate the Kappa for the complete dataframe at once:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

  # generate some sample data:
  n <- 100L
  x1 <- rnorm(n, 1.0, 2.0)
  x2 <- rnorm(n, -1.0, 0.5)
  y  <- rbinom(n, 1L, plogis(1 * x1 + 1 * x2))
  my_factor <- rep( c('A','B','C','D'), 25 )   
  
  df <- cbind(x1, x2, y, my_factor)
  
  # fit a model and make predictions:
  mod <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, "binomial")
  probs <- predict(mod, type = "response")
  
  # confusion matrix
  probs_round <- round(probs)
  
  t <- table(factor(probs_round, c(1,0)), factor(y, c(1,0)))
  ccm <- caret::confusionMatrix(t)
  
  # extract Kappa:
  ccm$overall[2]

> Kappa
> 0.5232
```

Although if I try to do `group_by` to generate the Kappa for every factor as a subgroup (see code below) it does not succeed. I suppose I need to nest `t` in a certain way in `df` although I don't know how:

```
  # extract Kappa for every subgroup with same factor (NOT WORKING CODE):

  df <- cbind(df, probs_round)
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  
  output <- df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(my_factor) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(t = table(factor(probs_round, c(1,0)), factor(y, c(1,0)))) %>%
    summarise(caret::confusionMatrix(t))

Expected output:

>my_factor Kappa
>1 A       0.51
>2 B       0.52
>3 C       0.53
>4 D       0.54
```

Is this correct and is this possible?
(the exact values for Kappa will be different due to the randomness in the sample data)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not clear what you want, could you share your expected output? Also, you might want to try to use `reprex::reprex()` next time, your example is not 100% reproducible.

Comment: @ Dan Chaltiel Sorry, I have adapted my example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the intermediate `mutate()` that's giving you trouble to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

df %>%
    group_by(my_factor) %>% 
    summarize(t = confusionMatrix(table(factor(probs_round, c(1,0)),
                                        factor(y, c(1,0))))$overall[2])
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  my_factor     t
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A         0.270
2 B         0.513
3 C         0.839
4 D         0.555
```

Answer (score 0):

The above approach is the easiest to get the desired results. But just to show whats possible, we can use your approach with `rowwise::nest_by` which groups the data set `rowwise`.

In the approach below we calculate a separate `glm` for each subgroup. I'm not sure if that's what you want to do.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)


# generate some sample data:
n <- 1000L

df <- tibble(x1 = rnorm(n, 1.0, 2.0),
             x2 = rnorm(n, -1.0, 0.5),
             y = rbinom(n, 1L, plogis(x1 + 1 * x1 + 1 * x2)),
             my_factor = rep( c('A','B','C','D'), 250))

output <- df %>%
  nest_by(my_factor) %>%
  mutate(y = list(data$y), 
         mod = list(glm(y ~ x1 + x2,
                        family = "binomial",
                        data = data)),
         probs = list(predict(mod, type = "response")),
         probs_round = list(round(probs)),
         t = list(table(factor(probs_round, c(1, 0)),
                  factor(y, c(1, 0)))),
         ccm = caret::confusionMatrix(t)$overall[2])

output %>%

  pull(ccm)
#>     Kappa     Kappa     Kappa     Kappa 
#> 0.7743682 0.7078112 0.7157761 0.7549340
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @ TimTeaFan In my data I have a factor variabele which does not improve the AUC of my model, although I had expectation it would. For that reason I try to group several metrics by this factor variabele to see if there is any difference in the metrics between the factor values. Although I don't know if this makes sense. I will try your method as well with specific models for every factorvalue. Thanks!

Comment: @user2165379: If your factor variable does not correlate with your outcome variable there is no need group your metrics, less even to caclulate a separate model for each group. If you use `rnorm` to generate random data then both approaches will lead to similar outcomes. Using one regression and grouping the metrics is a valditiy check to see, whether your approach performs better  or worse in some groups (meaingless if used with `rnorm`).  If you calculate a separate model for each group, then you are basically testing for interaction between the grouping var and your independent variable.

Comment: @ TimTeaFan, The rnorm data above is only as an example for the group_by problem. If I fit a model with a real factor in my real data there is no improvement in the AUC. Next I have fitted the model without this factor variabele and after this I have grouped_by this factor and calculated several metrics to see if there are differences in metrics between these groups. The reason I do this is to see if there possibly is some signal in the factor variabele (if there are differences in the outcomes between these groups). Or does this not make any sense?